# How to set background image for Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I want to set the background of my Gallery by an image (say  background.jpg ) in Drawable folder.

As the prototype of the   setBackground() method is

```
 void   setBackground(Drawable background)
Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background.
```

But I don't know how to  refer  to my image in this method.
I have tried to refer like this

```
Gallery galleryModified;
galleryModified.setBackground(background);
```

But getting error in second line, saying  unable to find resource.

Please reply if you know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you are setting background from a resource from drawable folder, which have id, R.drawable.background, if it is the case, try following:

```
galleryModified.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
```

Answer (score 0):

All resources in your project is parsed under R class automatically. You should always retrive them as an object, such as: `R.drawable.drawable_name` This is a basic way to retrieve many resource types. Just replace `drawable` keyword such as: 
`R.string.name_of_string_resource`
 `R.id.id_control`